# php retrieve data from mySQL db into form

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a simple example and I can't seem to make what's wrong. I have a simple form in which I'm sending data to my db

this is the form:

```
 <form action="selectDB.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="studentID" />
<input type="submit" name="send" />
</form>
```

I'm passing the value on the php page with this code:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['send'])){
    $var = $_POST[ 'studentID' ];
    //now you can use the var for an query to your database
    //please note: this very basic, without any security of injection
    $res = mysql_query( 'SELECT `*` FROM `student` WHERE `idStudent` LIKE \'%'.$var.'%\' ' );
    if( mysql_num_rows($res)){
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ); //get one (first) result
    }
}

?>

<script> location.href='editRegistration.php';</script>
```

then I'm using the script above to open the 3rd page in it I want to load the query result to the form in it. the problem is that I'm getting blank input fields and not set with the data from the db.
How do I fix the problem?
the 3rd page code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="registration" method="post" action="selectDB.php" name="send">
    <input type="text" name="studentID"  align= "right" class="textbox" value="<?php isset( $row[ '0' ] ) ? $row[ 'idStudent' ] : '' ?>" />  <span id="errorID"></span> <br/>  
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: You do the redirect with javascript. With this 3rd page has no data php $ row.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and you are simply assuming that your query worked. Did you do any debugging, like `var_dump($_POST)` to see if the form is submitting correctly? Checked the return value of `mysql_query()` for boolean false? Plus, your code as written tries to fetch a row of data, then simply outputs a javascript redirect without EVER outputting any of the data you fetched.

Comment: the query itself is incorrect, you are using 'LIKE' when you want '=', also putting a viarable straight into the query opens you up to injection. `SELECT * FROM student WHERE idStudent = '.$var` would be the query you might want but please learn to use mysqli or pdo.

Comment: I know or at least suspected I have a problem with outputting the data, I'll be happy if I could get the coorect way it should be done

Comment: @LucasHenrique how do i redirect without the javascript?

Comment: You REALLY need to stop using mysql_* functions for database interaction. They are deprecated, meaning that it won't even work sooner than later. Move over to PDO , it will make your issue non-existent also as you can use queries with anonymous parameters that you can set at the excecution of the query. This will get you started with great examples : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Comment: @user2674835 the answer was sufficient? You can use javascript, but pass along the GET data that need the 3rd page.

Comment: The answer was good, I still would appreciate a line of code that can pass the query result correctly to the 3rd page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
$res = mysql_query( 'SELECT `*` FROM `student` WHERE `idStudent` LIKE \'%'.$var.'%\' ' );
```

it should be:

```
$res = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `idStudent` = ".$var);
```

i think now it will work.

though it is not the correct way for querying the server but for a beginner it can be handy.